# How can I add equal gap between gameobjects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DropDown : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject dropdownPrefab;
    public int numberOfObjects;
    public float speed = 1.5f;
    public float duration = 5f;
    public Vector3 startPos;
    public Vector3 endPos;
    public float distanceToMove = 2f;
    public float gap;

    private List<GameObject> dropDownObjects = new List<GameObject>();
    private List<Vector3> endPositions = new List<Vector3>();

    private void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
        {
            dropDownObjects.Add(Instantiate(dropdownPrefab, transform.parent));
            endPositions.Add(new Vector3(dropDownObjects[i].transform.position.x, 
                dropDownObjects[i].transform.position.y + i + 2, 
                dropDownObjects[i].transform.position.z) - Vector3.up * distanceToMove);
        }

        startPos = dropDownObjects[0].transform.position;
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        StartCoroutine(StartDropObjects());
    }

    private IEnumerator StartDropObjects()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dropDownObjects.Count; i++)
        {
            // Random wait period before rotation starts
            if (i == 0)
            {
                //yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);
            }
            else
            {
                //yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(0, 2f));
            }

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);

            StartCoroutine(Drop(dropDownObjects[i].transform, duration, endPositions[i]));
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator Drop(Transform objectToDrop, float duration, Vector3 endpos)
    {
        float t = 0.0f;

        while (t < duration)
        {
            t += Time.deltaTime;
            objectToDrop.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(objectToDrop.transform.position, endpos, speed * Time.deltaTime);

            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The objects should be moving down but when I'm adding the gap in this case the gap is i + 2 for example if I = 0 then the gap is 2 then I = 1 so the gap will be 3 then I = 2 the gap is 4.

```
endPositions.Add(new Vector3(dropDownObjects[i].transform.position.x, 
                    dropDownObjects[i].transform.position.y + i + 2, 
                    dropDownObjects[i].transform.position.z) - Vector3.up * distanceToMove);
```

But I want to have equal gaps between the objects. For example if I will set the gap value to 1 there will be equal spaces/gaps between the objects and if the gap value is 5 then equal 5 between each two objects.

The problem now is that I getting higher each time by 1 so the gaps are not equal.

And also the objects are moving up and not down when I'm doing:  + i + 2

[image: Gaps]

In the screenshot the objects moved up instead down and the top two objects seems too close to each other. And the gaps are not equal.

But the idea is when the objects are moving to the target destination endPositions that each one will move to his on endPosition depending on the gap.

So in the end the objects should be like this :

[image: Moved Objects]

The first one is the one on the most bottom. The last one is the one on the top.
The first dropDownObjects[0] object moved to his endPosition the farest endPosition. In this case distanceToMove is set to 2.

Then dropDownObjects[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWx6O.jpg) is moving to his distanceToMove - the gap. And so on. This is the logic that in the end after all objects move they will have equal gaps.

And the first moved object is the one that should get to the distnaceToMove.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is not here:

```
endPositions.Add(new Vector3(dropDownObjects[i].transform.position.x, 
                dropDownObjects[i].transform.position.y + i + 2, 
                dropDownObjects[i].transform.position.z) - Vector3.up * distanceToMove);
```

But here:

```
private IEnumerator Drop(Transform objectToDrop, float duration, Vector3 endpos)
{
    float t = 0.0f;

    while (t < duration)
    {
        t += Time.deltaTime;
        objectToDrop.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(objectToDrop.transform.position, endpos, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Because you are using the same duration for all objects, but they have a different distance. The last objects just don't have time to finish their movement.

You can check this by changing your method Drop(...) to this code:

```
private IEnumerator Drop(Transform objectToDrop, float duration, Vector3 endpos)
{
    while (objectToDrop.transform.position != endpos)
    {
        objectToDrop.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(objectToDrop.transform.position, endpos, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: It give me exception out of index on this line : endPositions.Add(new Vector3(dropDownObjects[i].transform.position.x,
                dropDownObjects[i].transform.position.y + i + 2,
                dropDownObjects[i].transform.position.z) - Vector3.up * distanceToMove);

Comment: Why? I've changed only method Drop(...) in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would change how you're determining your `endPositions` to make it easier to configure.

I would define a starting distance and a max distance and you can calculate the gap programmatically by interpolating between the starting distance and `minDistanceToMove` `maxDistanceToMove` using `Mathf.Lerp` with a `t` of `(float)i/(numberOfObjects-1)`:

```
public float minDistanceToMove = 0.5f;
public float maxDistanceToMove = 2f;

private void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
    {
        dropDownObjects.Add(Instantiate(dropdownPrefab, transform.parent));

        float t = (float)i/(numberOfObjects-1);
        float distDown = Mathf.Lerp(minDistanceToMove,maxDistanceToMove,t);

        endPositions.Add(new Vector3(dropDownObjects[i].transform.position.x, 
            dropDownObjects[i].transform.position.y, 
            dropDownObjects[i].transform.position.z) - Vector3.up * distDown);
    }

    startPos = dropDownObjects[0].transform.position;
}
```

Alternatively, you can set only a `minDistanceToMove` and a gap size and then calculate `distDown` that way:

```
public float minDistanceToMove = 0.5f;
public float gapSize = 0.5f;

private void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
    {
        dropDownObjects.Add(Instantiate(dropdownPrefab, transform.parent));

        float distDown = minDistanceToMove + gapSize * i;

        endPositions.Add(new Vector3(dropDownObjects[i].transform.position.x, 
            dropDownObjects[i].transform.position.y, 
            dropDownObjects[i].transform.position.z) - Vector3.up * distDown);
    }

    startPos = dropDownObjects[0].transform.position;
}
```

---

Either way, you then need to change `Drop` to last for however long it takes for the panel to drop to its destination:

```
private IEnumerator Drop(Transform objectToDrop, float duration, Vector3 endpos)
{
    // duration is unused. It is in the method signature here to avoid 
    // confusion when swapping with the alternative below

    while (objectToDrop.transform.position != endPos)
    {
        objectToDrop.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(
                objectToDrop.transform.position, endpos, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can make each panel take the given duration and calculate the speed necessary to traverse the distance:

```
private IEnumerator Drop(Transform objectToDrop, float duration, Vector3 endpos)
{ 
    float mySpeed = Vector3.Distance(
            objectToDrop.transform.position, endpos) / duration;

    while (objectToDrop.transform.position != endPos)
    {
        objectToDrop.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(
                objectToDrop.transform.position, endpos, mySpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        yield return null;
    }
}
```